# Cannot deploy program with anchor on devnet

Tags: anchor, deploy

I am using anchor to deploy my program on devnet and deployment process got stuck (there is enough sol on my wallet).

```
anchor new test
anchor build
anchor deploy --provider.cluster devnet

Deploying workspace: https://api.devnet.solana.com
Upgrade authority: /root/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program "tmp"...
Program path: /workdir/test/tmp/target/deploy/tmp.so...
⠙   0.0% | Waiting for next block, 176 pending...   [block height 162679095; re-sign in 200 blocks
```

Here is the [transaction](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3QHz8etaWiR4BPQDcEVzdJy5jy4bLpsLE5buFpakrZFRimFAmhMqQq1S5f5Eu9S3Mazzx27e4Z85fDbSXRGxNfjT?cluster=devnet).

Is this got something to do with solana upgrade to verstion v1.13.4 on devnet that happend today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade solana cli to v1.13.2:

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.13.2/install)"
```

Now you can deploy your programs with anchor:

```
anchor deploy --provider.cluster devnet
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on solana-cli v. 1.9.29 Should I maybe downgrade the version to v1.13.2?

Comment: Answer for my question is YES, it works!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2619)