# Issue while executing anchor deploy

Tags: anchor, account, deploy

[image]

I am trying to deploy my solana smart contract and is receiving the error :account already in use or not an upgradeable program.
I tried the possible solution given in google like
npm run clean
npm run  build:program-rust
solana program deploy /path/to/program/helloworld.so
But the solution did not work out for me.
Please suggest any alternative for the issue

Comment: Duplicate: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/cannot-deploy-program-with-anchor-on-devnet/4155#4155

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot deploy program with anchor on devnet](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/cannot-deploy-program-with-anchor-on-devnet)